# SCons reports a dependency cycle when source and target file have the same suffix

Tags: scons, build-system

I am trying to get SCons to call uglify on a series of JavaScript files, for continuous integration reasons...

However even though the 'duplicate=False' flag is passed to 'env.SConscript' calls; to prevent scons from copying sources to the build output folder. It flags files with the same source and target extension as a dependency cycle. Take for example the following simplified project structure:

```
SConstruct
applications/SConscript
applications/frontend/SConscript
applications/frontend/scripts/app.js

-- SContruct --
UglifyBuilder = env.Builder(
  action = 'uglify --source $SOURCE --output $TARGET',
  suffix = '.js',
  single_source = True)

env['BUILDERS']['Uglify'] = UglifyBuilder

env.SConscript('applictions/SConscript', 'env',
    variant_dir=os.path.join('build', 'debug', 'applications'),
    duplicate=False)

-- applications/SConscript --
env.SConscript('frontend/SConscript', 'env', duplicate=False)

-- applications/frontend/SConscript --
env.Uglify('scripts/app.js')
```

When you run SCons on this (clean or not) the following output is generated; Stating that there is a dependency cycle between the target files:

```
$ scons applications/frontend/
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: build/debug/applications/frontend
scons: `applications/frontend' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.

scons: *** Found dependency cycle(s):
  build/debug/applications/frontend/scripts/app.js -> build/debug/applications/frontend/scripts/app.js
```

I also tried to pass an absolute path to the source file, but unfortunately with the same result. And sure I could change the output suffix to '.min.js', but there are other cases to come up with that output files with the same leader-path/filename as some arbitrary input source.

Am I misunderstanding SCons here? Or can somebody point me in the right direction of solving this?

Because if this is one of those cases where 'it isn't a bug it's a feature' applies I am going to pull my hair out. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really sorry for you and your hair, but this behaviour doesn't have anything to do with variant_dir, and the "duplicate" option won't help you out either.
What your example boils down to is:

- You have a file "`app.js`".
- You have an `Uglify` Builder, mapping `*.js` files to `*.js` files.
- You tell this Builder to do his stuff with "`app.js`".

Of course this leads to a dependency cycle, because your source and target have the same filename. Note, that SCons detects the cycle from `build/debug/.../app.js` to itself...and *not* to `applications/frontend/scripts/app.js`.

For breaking this cycle, you have to either rename one of your suffixes (`*.in` for source files?), or the file stem, e.g. you could name your source file "`app_pretty.js`" and then call

```
env.Uglify('scripts/app.js', 'scripts/app_pretty.js')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am afraid this is the case indeed.

On what grounds is "Of course this leads to a dependency cycle, because your source and target have the same filename." a logical thing. If the duplication of source files is disabled you are actually separating input and output paths. Thus imho it would also make sense to treat paths in a different subtree from the root of the project independently. As in why would SCons be looking in the target path for source files unless explicitly asked, e.g. when target becomes source for another target.

Comment: The `duplicate` option isn't doing what you expect it to do. The build actually happens (note, this is a mental concept only) in the "variant directory", and usually all source files get copied to the "variant dir" (duplicate=1). By setting "duplicate=0" you simply allow SCons to use the "remote source" file with the path to the folder where it comes from in the current build step. But this doesn't prevent SCons from detecting a cyclic dependency between the local target Node "app.js" and the local source Node "app.js".

Comment: Only after resolving this ambiguity, and trying to access and read the contents of the file, SCons would resolve its name and path to either the local "app.js" if it exists, or the "app.js" in the remote source folder.